# question about asymptotic barriers of given algorithem

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

i got the next algorithm:

```
Algorithm Alg (int n)
{
 Proc1(n);
 Proc2(n);
 Proc3(n);
}
```

and i know that the run time of each Proc function is:

[the run time of each Proc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Owhs.png)

Respectively. , while Ta(n) is the full runtime of the program.

and i need to tell if the next claims are necessarily correct or not:

[the clamis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtJJ2.png)

I almost sure that the first claim is correct, but dont sure about the next ones, i would like to get some help with this qustion.

Comment: According to you, what would be `Ta(n)`?

Comment: i think it will be omega of n^2log(n), because it's the dominant run time of the sums.

Comment: Since you know it will be `Ω(n^2 * log n)`, in which claim are you facing difficulty?

Comment: I just dont sure about the correctness of my answer / my examples. i think that the answer to 2) and 3) is not necessarily correct, and for example if the runtime is equal to n^2log(n) than the secend claim is false. and if the runtime is n^4 (which is possiable) than the third claim is false.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the algorithm in the question:

```
Algorithm Alg(int n)
{
    Proc1(n);
    Proc2(n);
    Proc3(n);
}
```

Here is the time complexity of the above three functions:

```
Proc1(n) : T(n) = Ω(n^2 * log n)
Proc2(n) : T(n) = Θ(n^2)
Proc3(n) : T(n) = O(n)
```

*Combining above three, we can be sure of one thing that the lower bound of the algorithm is:* `Ta(n) = Ω(n^2 * log n)`.

---

Here are the claims we have to answer:

```
Ta(n) = Ω(n)
Ta(n) = Ω(n^3)
Ta(n) = O(n^3)
```

The ***first claim is true***. Since `Ta(n) = Ω(n^2 * log n)` does imply that `Ta(n) = Ω(n)`. It is an weak lower bound.

The ***second claim is false*** since n^3 > n^2 * log n.

The ***last claim is also false***. *We are only sure about the lower bound of `Ta`. We can not say what is its upper bound*. Hence, `Ta(n) = O(n^3)` is possible but it might be wrong too.